# Hybris Flexible Search fetch records created 1 hour ago

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I need a flexible search query in order to fetch the products created 1 hour ago from current date, I have tried this:

```
select * from {product} where {creationtime} < current_date - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Also this:

```
  final FlexibleSearchQuery flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery("SELECT {pk} FROM {Product} where {creationtime} < ?inputDate");
        flexibleSearchQuery.addQueryParameter("inputDate", ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().minus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS));
```

However, none of these solutions actually worked, the first one returns the products created in the interval of 1 hour but ignores the actual day and month, looks like it only takes in count the hours and minutes but ignores the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use > operator like below:

```
  final FlexibleSearchQuery flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery("SELECT {pk} FROM {Product} where {creationtime} > ?inputDate");
    flexibleSearchQuery.addQueryParameter("inputDate", LocalTime.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS));
```

And don't forget about server and app timezone maybe different.

Comment: It throws `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Hours` Exception, why?

Comment: Sorry we need to use LocalTime instead of LocalDate. LocalDate type not supporting time.